# After I've updated Latex, why I still get an error?

Tags: latex

I am using MacTex on my Mac and try to us Texmaker as my editor.

However, when I type `\usepackage{algorithms}` in Texmaker, it always warn me that `algorithms.sty` is not found. I also tried this in Texshop, the error was the same.

I firstly checked TexLive Utility to make sure algorithms package is installed. It gives an yes. Then I tried to copy `algorithms.sty` from `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms` folder to `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base` folder and execute texhash to update. Still not working and get the same error.

Can someone help me with this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't copy around in the `texmf-dist/` folder.

Answer (score 2):

[`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) is actually a *bundle* that provides two separate *packages":

- `algorithm`

  Provides the `algorithm` float and float-associated accessories.
- `algorithmic`

  A environment that provides a layout of algorithm pseudo-code.

So, to use `algorithms`, you need either or both of

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```